# (0 - Sum) Representable by Numbers in a Set

Tags: summation

**Given:** *K* is a finite set of positive integers.
The sum of all numbers in the set can be found, *S*.

**Given:** *$K_i$* is the subset of *K* containing all numbers less than *$2^i$*.
The sum of all numbers in *$K_i$* is *$S_i$*.

**Given:** All numbers from $[0, 2^i)$ are representable by the sum of a subset of the numbers in *$K_i$*.

**Prove:** All numbers from $[2^i, S_i]$ are representable by summing a subset of the numbers in *$K_i$*.



It should extend from this proof that if *K* contains a number, *x* in the range $[2^i, S_i]$ that all numbers between $[0, S_i + x]$ are representable by the sum of a subset of $K_i ∪ x$.

This question stems from me trying to certify this algorithm: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21079874/2642059

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For a number, *y* in $[2^i, S_i]$ begin by subtracting the largest number in *$K_i$* to the smallest until the total is 0 or negative. **Proof:** We are guaranteed that for any *y* by subtracting enough numbers from the set *$K_i$* we will reach a 0 or a negative total because $y \leq S_i$.
2. If the total comes to 0 the numbers from *$K_i$* which were subtracted from *y* can be summed to form *y*.
3. If the total comes to a negative number, when we subtract an element of *$K_i$*, *z* from the total then we know that we can form the number that we should have been subtracted to reach 0 because we were given: "All numbers from $[0, 2^i)$ are representable by the sum of a subset of the numbers in *$K_i$*." **Proof:** Neither *z* nor any number that we have already subtracted from *y* could be used in the formation of the difference between the total and because that number must be smaller than *z*, which is the smallest number we have subtracted so far. Therefore a subset of *$K_i$* exists which can form this difference, and none of those numbers have been used yet.